# Oracle fusion middleware 12c weblogic installation window doesn't be shown automatically after extracting fmw_12.2.1.0.0_wls.jar file in cmd

Tags: weblogic12c

When I want to install oracle weblogic using fmw_12.2.1.0.0_wls.jar file in windows 10, the installation window doesn't be shown automatically and I just get this message in cmd : press any key to exit. why? How can I fix it?

This picture shows my problem:

[image: my problem]

Comment: What does the 'logs' that are located in `C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Temp\OraInstall2018-02-26-01-57-28AM` say? There should be a `.err` file in that folder that is likely to help you.

Comment: There are some checking options in log file and results of all of them are  succeed or passed. There are not any errors in log file and there is not .err file. @radimpe

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with your java. Try downloading and installing Oracle's Java 8. FMW 12c is certified with Java 8 and runs best with Oracle's Java - JDK/SDK to be specific. Openjdk is not certified and won't work for an install.

Could also be an issue with your X display. Ensure that you have the display variable correctly set and a Xhost client running. Test your X display with another program to verify functionality.  If you have X issues, try unsetting the DISPLAY variable and have it run the character based installer.